# Can't connect with SSH on Windows 10. I don't know what password do I have to put

Tags: ssh, windows-10, openssh

I just install SSh server and client in 2 PC with Windows 10 OS. I pretend to connect but when I install these services i triend to connect with Putty and ask me for the password, I enter the password of my PC and it was wrong, i don't know if i need to put an other passowrd or if i need to enter the client password.`pc@192.168.1.54's password: Permission denied, please try again. pc@192.168.1.54's password:`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

type this instead:

```
ssh idofpc@hostnameofpc
```

example:

```
ssh administrator@192.168.1.1
```

reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse